# Default values in regular expressions if pattern does not match

Tags: php, regex, default-value

I'm trying to build a PHP regexp pattern that would:

1. Capture "openid" if test string is "login/openid"
2. Would use "index" if test string is just "login" (without a trailing slash).

login(?:/(.+))? - this would capture whatever is after the slash, and it works fine.

However, can I build a regexp to provide a "default" value if pattern IS NOT matched (i.e. there's no slash).

Please do not suggest workarounds, I only need a pattern if it's at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, regular expressions can only match text that is there, not "invent" new text (e.g., a default value). So you can't do it with a regex alone.

You need an `if` statement:

```
if (preg_match('%login(?:/(.+))?%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "index";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to capture a group that doesn't exist in the source text. I think that is not possible with a regex alone.

I think your only chance is to implement the logic for the "index" value directly in php.